# Check if IP is in other IPs networks range and find next free IP

Tags: c++, networking

I currently try to get a function going that checks if an IP Adress is part of the Network of a network adapter on the system. The IPs are in the format `uint32_t` (or'd ABCD together).

I have the IP I want to check, lets call it `checkip`, the IP of the network interface, lets call it `otherip` and the network adapters subnet mask, lets call it `othersubnet`.

Now I want to start searching from `10.0.0.0` on upwards to find an IP that is not part of this network adapters IP Range. I have written something together that manually does an `if` hell and has a lot of bugs. What I wanted to ask: Is there a way to check if an IP is part of a Networks IP range and if it is, find the next IP that is not part of that network.

Example:

My Network interface has the IP `10.0.1.100` with the subnet `255.255.0.0`, then `10.0.0.1` would be part of that network. But how to check that programatically as simple as possible and how to find out that the next free IP would be `10.1.0.1`?

Comment: Think of the subnet mask as a bit-mask. Once converted to a an `uint32_t` it's easy to figure out what bits you can change to change the network (the first non-zero bit of the subnet mask).

Comment: There is a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that explains how to determine if an address is in a network ("_This is the method a source host uses to determine if it a destination host on the same network as the source host._"). There is also a section that explains how to find the common network between two address. Plus, just about everything else you wanted to know about IPv4 addressing and subnetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the IPs and subnet mask in `uint32_t` format, it is very simple to check if the IPs are on the same subnet.  Simply use the bitwise AND operator to mask the two IPs with the subnet mask and then check if the results are the same value:

```cpp
bool isOnSameNetwork = (checkip & othersubnet) == (otherip & othersubnet);
```

For example:

`(10.0.1.100 & 255.255.0.0) == 10.0.0.0`
`(10.0.0.1 & 255.255.0.0) == 10.0.0.0`

So they are on the same subnet.

Given an adapter's IP address and subnet mask, you can determine the entire range of that adapter's subnet fairly easily, again using bitwise operators:

```cpp
uint32_t networkAddr = (otherip & othersubnet);
uint32_t hostMask = ~othersubnet;
uint32_t firstHost = networkAddr | 1;
uint32_t lastHost = networkAddr | (hostMask - 1);
uint32_t broadcastAddr = networkAddr | hostMask;
```